# System.exit working in "sbt run" but not in .jar

Tags: java, scala, jar, akka, sbt-assembly

When shutting down my program I need to let my akka actors finish what they're doing before shutting down, so I have a shutdown hook:

```
sys.addShutdownHook(
    {
      log.info("\n shutting down startWorkScheduler\n")
      assignWorkScheduler.cancel()
      log.info("\ntelling manager to shutdown gracefully\n")
      manager ! Manager.ShutdownGracefully
      //spam shutdown messages until we exit
      val resendShutDown = system.scheduler.schedule(5 seconds, 2 seconds){
        manager ! Manager.ShutdownGracefully
      }
      system.awaitTermination()
    }
```

and elsewhere I wait for a "all ok, you can shutdown" message:

```
case Terminated(httpDlrSqlRouter) => {
      println("received terminated message from http router")
      if(shuttingDown) {
        println("httpDlrRouter done, shutting down......")
        log.info("httpDlrRouter done, shutting down......")
        context.system.shutdown()
        java.lang.System.exit(0)
      }else{
        log.warning("httpDlrRouter terminated, don't know why!")
      }
    }
```

When I run the code using `sbt run` it works as expected: kill or CTRL+c finishes the work, prints "httpDlrRouter done, shutting down......" and exits.

When I build a .jar using `sbt assembly` and run it using `java -jar filename.jar` it does the same **except** actually exiting, it just hangs until i kill it with `kill -9`

do I need any alternatives to `System.exit` or some configuration to make it work?

Comment: From the documentation of `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`: "Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly." I think you are causing trouble with `system.awaitTermination()`.

Comment: Entirely possible, but it works in one scenario and not the other, consistently and regardless of "a lot of work to finish" or "no work to finish"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently changing

```
java.lang.System.exit(0)
```

to

```
Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0)
```

solved the problem